# & for running a command in the background

Tags: linux

when i run

```
$ ls -R / &
```

although the `&` (which suppose to relegate the process into the background) i end up having to sit through the entire listing of my system.
pressing CTRL+C or CTRL+Z doesn't help.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: "what am i doing wrong?" What are you intending to do?

Comment: just see what happens when i send a process into the background for practice/learning reasons @muru

Comment: Then maybe pick commands that don't have lots of output. You can't do anything about the output once the process has started. If you want to stop the process, see

Comment: It sounds like you saw what happens, then - what is the question you want answered at this point?

Comment: @muru so the outputs come in even if the job is in the background? is that stdout and i could send it to the /dev/null?

Comment: @DanielEliazarov yes. If you want to discard the output, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109986/70524

Comment: @muru and why does it show me exit 1 when i do $ ls -R / 1>/dev/null 2>&1 & when i go chck the status in jobs -l?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're after, but you can still a rogue background job that fills your screen with garbage this way: Ctrl-S, blindly enter `kill %`, Ctrl-M, Ctrl-Q (or Ctrl-S, `fg`, Ctrl-M, Ctrl-Q, Ctrl-C).

Answer (score 1):

When you start `ls -R /` in the background, the command is immediately started and control is given back to the invoking shell (your interactive shell).  However, the standard output stream and the standard error stream of `ls` are still connected to the terminal, so that's why you see the output of the command in the terminal.

[In comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521863/for-running-a-command-in-the-background#comment964651_521863) you ask a follow-up question that shows that you know that you may redirect the output of the command to `/dev/null` to avoid having it stream to the terminal:

```
ls -R / >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The follow-up question is "Why does it show me `Exit 1` when I check the job's status with `jobs -l`.

You get a non-zero exit status from `ls` because it did not run completely successfully.  It did not, because you tried to do a recursive listing of all files on the whole system, and, presumably, some of the directories on your systems are not readable by the user that you used to run the command as.  If you had not redirected the standard error stream to `/dev/null` (by removing `2>&1` from the command line), you would probably have seen errors in the terminal.